# twig import a macro file by variable name for the 'as' part

Tags: twig

the syntax is `{% import 'forms.html' as forms %}`

where forms is literal name you assign

I need to have the name in a variable like :

`{% set name='forms' %}` and then `{% import 'forms.html' as name %}`

but it doesn't work
any suggestion ?

Comment: You can't do this with a regular `import`. Why you want this anyway?

Comment: I need to assign file name and import name runtime with file name it works not for import name

Comment: Yes but why you want to do this? I don't see any benefits to trying to include an `import` under a dynamic name

Comment: my module dinamically generate templates inclusion of files are repeated the system insure you don't have duplicate names